# I need to use substring, but I need the second parameter to be inclusive

Tags: java, string, substring

I've got a String that I need to cycle through and create every possible substring. For example, if I had "HelloWorld", "rld" should be one of the possibilities. The String method, substring(int i, int k) is exclusive of k, so if

```
|H|e|l|l|o|W|o|r|l|d|
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

then

substring(7,9) returns "rl"

How would I work around this and get it to work inclusively? I understand why a substring shouldn't be able to equal the String it was created from, but in this case it would be very helpful to me in this case.

Example from Codingbat: http://codingbat.com/prob/p137918

What I was able to come up with:

```
public String parenBit(String str) {
  String sub;
  if (str.charAt(0) == '(' && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ')')
    return str;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < str.length(); k++) {
      sub = str.substring(i,k);

    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding 1?

Comment: Sidenote: why are you returning `null`?

Comment: substring(7,10) in other words just make sure that k = str.length for the largest value of k

Comment: Ah.  Reading the CodingBat page I think you have misunderstood on two grounds.  First, your solution is not recursive.  Second, it is not a solution to the problem posed, which is not to generate all possible substrings - but to find the substring between '(' and )' [inclusive of parens].

Comment: `I understand why a substring shouldn't be able to equal the String it was created from` Why? I would call "helloworld" a substring of "helloworld". I would also in general, call A a subset of A(so long as we're not talking about proper subsets)

Comment: A substring *can* be equal to the String it was created from: "hello".substring(0, 5).equals("hello").

Answer (score 1):

The transformation between exclusive to inclusive is simple when you're working in integers. You just add 1.

```
String substringInclusive(String s, int a, int b)
{
    return s.substring(a, b+1);
}
```

Comment: OH MAN !!Jon Skeet had answered that 32 minutes befor you .

Comment: @iShaalan if it's the right answer, then it's the right answer. The question needs an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet rightly pointed out that adding 1 would be the right thing to do as the second parameter in String.substring  is not inclusive.

However your answer is not recursive, below is the recursive solution:

```
public String parenBit(String str) {
    if(str.charAt(0)!='(')
      return parenBit(str.substring(1));

    if(str.charAt(0)=='('&&(str.charAt(str.length()-1)!=')'))
      return parenBit(str.substring(0, str.length()-1));
   return str;
}
```